# Reusable delegate

Tags: c#, delegates

Apologies if this question comes across as "basic" but I haven't done much with delegates and i'm struggling to stumble across the correct syntax - if this is at all possible.

I'm using a delegate like this:

```
Func<KeyValuePair<string, PostMeta>, bool> filter = x =>
x.Value.Category == pageMeta.Value.Category && x.Key != pageMeta.Key;
```

However, I find myself reusing this unwieldly part `Func<KeyValuePair<string, PostMeta>, bool>` again and again - it feels like it should work like a property getter/setter but i'm not sure.

Here's some non working code to demonstrate further:

Declaration

```
delegate void PostFilter<Func<KeyValuePair<string, PostMeta>, bool>>();
```

Usage:

```
PostFilter = x => x.Value.Category == pageMeta.Value.Category && x.Key != pageMeta.Key;
```

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to define a delegate type which accepts one parameter of type `KeyValuePair<string, PostMeta>` and returns `bool` (as your first code snippet suggests), use this declaration:

```
delegate bool PostFilterDelegate(KeyValuePair<string, PostMeta> param);
```

Then you may use a variable of the `PostFilterDelegate` type:

```
PostFilterDelegate PostFilter = x =>
    x.Value.Category == pageMeta.Value.Category && x.Key != pageMeta.Key;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Unfortunately, this answer changes the signature from Func<TKey,TValue> so I can no longer pass this generically to other methods without modification or an interface.

Answer (score 1):

Other than defining delegate, one more option is to use [using](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423(v=vs.100).aspx) directive to create type aliases. Here is several examples below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using EqualsFunc = System.Func<int, int, bool>;
using PostFilter = Func<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, PostMeta>, bool>; 
using MyPair = System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,int>;

namespace TypeAlias
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            EqualsFunc equals = (a, b) => a == b;
            var result == equals(1, 2); //false

            PostFilter filter = x =>
            x.Value.Category == pageMeta.Value.Category && x.Key != pageMeta.Key;
            var filterResult = filter(new MyPair("key",5),10); 
        }
    }
}
```